# Android Issue In YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI.?

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api

Hi facing issue in YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI, here is the error i'm facing

```
W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: Forcefully created overlay:acqm@cada64 
helper:Lazy@241a4cd view:null status: ....... {...}
```

**NOTE** - i have two activity class if user enter `FirstActivity` video is working fine. If user change activity from `FirstActivity` to `SecondActivity` in SecondActivity also video working fine, if user using system back button navigate to FirstActivity video not playing continuously loading happening but video not playing.(Added image for reference)

loading same Activity if user clicking button like this(FirstActivity and SecondActivity are same in my case, just for under standing purpose explained two activityes)

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(YoutubeVideoPlay.this, YoutubeVideoPlay.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Here is the code sample i'm using

FirstActivity.java

```
    public class FirstActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    public static final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
    private String url = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    private String VIDEO_ID;

    private YouTubePlayerFragment myYouTubePlayerFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtube);

        myYouTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtubeplayerfragment);
        myYouTubePlayerFragment.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
        VIDEO_ID = getYoutubeVideoId(url);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity .this, FirstActivity .class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            String errorMessage = String.format("There was an error initializing the YouTubePlayer (%1$s)",
                    errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
        }
    }

    protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerfragment);
    }

    public static String getYoutubeVideoId(String youtubeUrl) {
        String video_id = "";
        if (youtubeUrl != null && youtubeUrl.trim().length() > 0 && youtubeUrl.startsWith("http")) {

            String expression = "^.*((youtu.be" + "\\/)" + "|(v\\/)|(\\/u\\/w\\/)|(embed\\/)|(watch\\?))\\??v?=?([^#\\&\\?]*).*"; // var regExp = /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;
            CharSequence input = youtubeUrl;
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                String groupIndex1 = matcher.group(7);
                if (groupIndex1 != null && groupIndex1.length() == 11)
                    video_id = groupIndex1;
            }
        }
        return video_id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes , youtube main single global player if you start new player ,previous player will release automatically.

So you need restart your youtube player again when resume your activity

Comment: can you attach that code ? you need to recreate player and seek to your last seek position of player.

Comment: tried like this onResume()

     @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        myYouTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtubeplayerfragment);
    }

Comment: you just tried to initialized youtube fragment object

Comment: call this again   myYouTubePlayerFragment.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168796/discussion-between-rajasekaran-m-and-nagarjunareddy).